# Creating an App that Contains a Group of Applications

Tags: android

Hello and thanks in advance for the help

I have a series of Android apps that I am using.  Whenever I recommend these apps to someone, I have to go over each one individually.

I wanted to know if it was possible to create a single application that will:

1. Download all of the individual apps all at once and install them
2. Create an app icon that when launched creates a submenu with all of the related apps and a help file to walk the user through each one.

Is this possible?  If so, how difficult is it to do?

Thanks again for your help

Dave

Answer (score 1):

1. For the download and installation, it's not difficult. You'll just have to get the market URL of all the apps you want to include, and then use a custom [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) to download and install them (something using [`ACTION_VIEW`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW) should do the trick
2. For the second part, you could create your launcher, and then have a screen with some buttons and an help screen. It shouldn't be too hard to do.

Comment: I wrote up some additional details.  We would like a single application that will:
1.)  When you download the application, it downloads and installs all of the other application. 
3,)  When you click on this applications, all of the other related applications can be seen and can be launched from the same screen
4.) Included in the application will be a file that will allow us to customize, add or change the applications that are included, allow us to change the logo file on the welcome screen and allow us to update the help files.   Can you give us a ballpark estimate?  Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, this is a Q&A forum, you know, not a consulting agency. All we can give you is some technical solutions on how to do this, but estimates depends on the coder (and besides that, I already have estimates to do for my work, so I think most people here would prefer not to do them for fun). Short answer : find a coder, ask him the estimate.

Answer (score 0):

"background batch app install" is not possible on a basic (not rooted) device.

But you can easily create a "launcher app" listing all the app you want to share and, using "Intents" and "PackageManager", letting the user open it if it's already installed of downloaded the app if it's not.